# How to make EF Core search correct schema for postgre being case-sensitive?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

I'm aware that postgre is case-sensitive when using double quotes. I can't cant EF to perform the correct search path.

This is my context:

```
public class PostgresDbContext : MyContext
{
    public PostgresDbContext(DbContextOptions options, IConfiguration configuration) : base(options, configuration)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(PostgresDbContext).Assembly.FullName));
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

So I've set the default schema to public.

My table names are uppercase so if I query the schema with the following query in pgAdmin it works as expected:

```
select * from public."Customers"
```

But when EF Core executes my code it throws this error:

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P01: relation "public.Customers" does not exist
```

So it appears it does recognize that I'm using the default schema, but the double quotes are off.

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v. 5.0.10

Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL v. 5.0.10

Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design v 1.1.0

I created the initial migrations through an idempotent-migration script.

Comment: Why not just doing yourself a favor and not using case sensitive object names in the database? As you see that just causes trouble. And "pretty" headers and such are a job for the presentation layer anyway.

Comment: There are other constraints in the project, it already has an existing scheme in another provider .. you are right that it would be easier if there is no easy solution here

Comment: Your entity framework seems to not know how to handle quoting schemas. If you only have the one and it is "public" then you can just not specify it. If it isn't "public" then you will need to set `search_path` and then not specify it.

Comment: @RichardHuxton If I remove the "HasDefaultSchema" line then I get this error instead

`Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P01: relation "Customers" does not exist`

Comment: You can try to set the table name manually like with `[Table("public.\"Customers\"")]` in your customer entity class.

Comment: Ask question here: https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg,  I can't believe that they have missed such escaping.